# БЭМ использование классов-цветов

Tags: css, классы, бэм, методология

В документации написано следующее

```
<!-- Неверно. Описывается внешний вид -->
<div class="red-text"></div>
```

Но если я именно хочу написать класс text-red и использовать его к тексту, который должен быть красный. И пусть кроме этого класса больше у тега не будет ничего. Если так нельзя делать, тогда как?

Каждый раз писать блок__элемент_модификатор. С точки зрения размера файла, такой способ проигрывает в разы

Comment: А вы точно правильно поняли всю суть БЭМ? Делайте как сказано в инструкции и закрывайте глаза на размер файла.

Comment: Длинная портянка классов это минус БЭМ. Если у вас заказчик/начальник с маузером возле головы не стоит, используйте свой `.red-text` на здоровье. Ну или `text-block.text-block_red`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут 2 варианта: 1)БЭМ; 2) не БЭМ.

Вот хороший ролик с размышлениями о БЭМ: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBgHdSOj33A

Еще emmet поддерживает БЭМ, если лень писать и копипастить. 
Размер тут не главное. Минификаторы порежут все лишнее.